# How to pass one variable as another variable in a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a SQL variable `mem_dep` When I am using it directly in variable `sql` then it is working absolutely fine. It is printing proper SQL statement but when I am passing another variable `cat` in variable `sql` with the value "`mem_dep`" then it is not working fine. It is just printing value of `cat`

```
mem_dep = """SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DT2_BUSINESS = '{Business_date}'"""
cob = "20223456"
cat = "mem_dep"
```

Below code is working absolutely fine

```
def calc():
    sql = mem_dep.format(Business_date = cob)
    print(sql)
```

Output:

```
calc() # calling function
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DT2_BUSINESS = '20223456' # printing sql
```

But below code is not working if I am passing variable `cat` in a function with the same value as variable name `mem_dep`

```
def calc(cat):
    sql = cat.format(Business_date = cob)
    print(sql)
```

Output:

```
calc(cat) # calling function
mem_dep #printing sql
```

How can I pass SQL variable as a variable in the function in this case?

I tried below code also but not working

```
def calc(cat):
    tmp_sql = "{}".format(cat)
    sql = tmp_sql.format(Business_date = cob)
    print(sql)
```

Output:

```
calc(cat) # calling function
mem_dep #printing sql
```

Expected output:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DT2_BUSINESS = '20223456' # printing sql
```

Comment: But I can't parameterize mem_dep and other SQLs like this if I am not passing variable cat in the function

Comment: change `cat = "mem_dep"` to `cat = mem_dep`. You set cat  to string "mem_dep" not to its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand `cat` has the name of the SQL variable which contains your SQL string. And you want to access the SQL string from `cat` without knowing the value of `cat`. You can use getattr for this purpose and wrap everything in a class like below:

```py
class SQLCalc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mem_dep = """SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DT2_BUSINESS = '{Business_date}'"""
        self.cob = "20223456"
        self.cat = "mem_dep"

    def calc(self):
        sql = getattr(self, self.cat).format(Business_date = self.cob)
        print(sql)

sql_calc = SQLCalc()
sql_calc.calc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!!!
I got it resolved by using eval(cat)

answer would be

```
sql = eval(cat).format(Business_date = cob)
```

Answer (score 0):

for this output

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DT2_BUSINESS = '20223456'
```

You have to give mem_dep as an argument in the calc()

```
calc(mem_dep)
```

Comment: but how to pass mem_dep variable as another variable in the function. I want to pass mem_dep value via another variable

Comment: Then remove quotes from the "mem_dep" in the cat variable make it as cat = mem_dep

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
mem_dep = """SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DT2_BUSINESS = '{Business_date}'"""
cob = "20223456" 

def calc(sql_template, buisness_date): 
    return sql_template.format(Business_date = buisness_date)
    
mem_dep_result = calc(mem_dep, cob)
print(mem_dep_result)
```